# How to hide breadcrumbs from all pages in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have been trying to remove this breadcrumb feature from my WordPress site but don't know how to do. Please help. It shows in every page.

I want to remove from all pages.

[image: link]

Comment: These are called breadcrumbs. These can be removed easily by adding `display:none;` in CSS. Could you share the link of your website?

Comment: Check your theme options. It should have an option to hide this. Overriding the CSS is not a good practice as you have the option to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
 nav.woocommerce-breadcrumb {
    display: none;
 }
```

This can be added via a child theme or within your WordPress Customizer
.

Answer (score 0):

In your child-theme or custom CSS box, add the following code:

```
.woocommerce-breadcrumb {
  display: none;
}
```

If that doesn't work, use `!important` like so:

```
.woocommerce-breadcrumb {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Do not use `!important` unless necessary and only edit your child-theme or you will lose this modification on next theme update.

It's best to put the above code in the CSS box if your theme has one. It can usually be found under 'Theme Options' in wp-admin.

The code I gave will simply hide the concerned CSS class.

Hope this helps.